# Cmake error while building OGRE

Tags: build, cmake, ogre

I am building OGRE source using `cmake ../../ogre_src_v1-8-1` in my `build` directory. I have looked into many similar errors but nothing has worked out for me.

The output of the cmake command mentioned above gives following output:

```
-- Configuring OGRE 1.8.1
-- Detected g++ 4.8

-- Enabling GCC visibility flags
-- Search path: /home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/../Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/../Dependencies
-- Looking for ZLIB...
-- Found ZLIB: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
-- Looking for ZZip...
-- Found ZZip: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzzip.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzzip.so
-- Looking for FreeImage...
-- checking for module 'freeimage'
--   package 'freeimage' not found
-- Found FreeImage: optimized;/usr/lib/libfreeimage.so;debug;/usr/lib/libfreeimage.so
-- Looking for FREETYPE...
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/../Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/../Dependencies;/usr/local;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/build/../Dependencies;/home/kamal/Documents/ogre_src_v1-8-1/../Dependencies;/usr/local;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-- Could not locate FREETYPE
-- Looking for Cg...
-- checking for module 'Cg'
--   package 'Cg' not found
-- Found Cg: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCg.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCg.so
-- Looking for POCO...
-- checking for module 'POCO'
--   package 'POCO' not found
-- Could not locate POCO
-- Looking for TBB...
-- Found TBB: optimized;/usr/lib/libtbb.so;debug;/usr/lib/libtbb.so
-- Looking for TBB_MALLOC...
-- Found TBB_MALLOC: optimized;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so;debug;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so
-- Looking for TBB_MALLOC_PROXY...
-- Found TBB_MALLOC_PROXY: optimized;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so;debug;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so
-- Looking for GLSL_Optimizer...
-- checking for module 'GLSL_Optimizer'
--   package 'GLSL_Optimizer' not found
-- Could not locate GLSL_Optimizer
-- Looking for HLSL2GLSL...
-- checking for module 'HLSL2GLSL'
--   package 'HLSL2GLSL' not found
-- Could not locate HLSL2GLSL
-- Looking for OIS...
-- Found OIS: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOIS.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOIS.so
-- Looking for Softimage...
-- Could not locate Softimage
-- Looking for CppUnit...
-- checking for module 'cppunit'
--   package 'cppunit' not found
-- Could not locate CppUnit
CMake Error at CMake/Utils/MacroLogFeature.cmake:100 (MESSAGE):

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- The following REQUIRED packages could NOT be located on your system.

-- Please install them before continuing this software installation.

-- If you are in Windows, try passing -DOGRE_DEPENDENCIES_DIR=<path to dependencies>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

+ freetype: Portable font engine <http://www.freetype.org>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMake/Dependencies.cmake:234 (MACRO_DISPLAY_FEATURE_LOG)
CMakeLists.txt:194 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How to resolve this issue? Any help shall be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's missing the `freetype` library which is required for building OGRE. Make sure that the lib itself and the development package is installed on your system.
This might help, the OGRE wiki page with installation instructions for the prerequisites for various linux distros [Install OGRE Prerequisite](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Prerequisites&tikiversion=Linux)

Comment: I have both `libfreetype6` and `libfreetype6-dev` installed on my system.

Comment: OK good, but CMake does not find it. You can set variables for the libs and include directory manually, I find doing that via `cmake-gui` is faster especially if you are fiddling around.

Comment: Thanks. Using `cmake-gui` helped out to comprehend it more specifically.